# сортировка модели по умолчанию Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

hiall!

Подскажите, плз, есть ли в фалконе возможность сортировки записей в модели по умолчанию?

В данный момент создал 2 модели - задачи и комменты к таковым, после чего связал их по задача->id.

Хочу, чтобы задачи->комменты сразу возвращали отсортированный по дате DESC массив с лимитом 10. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

связь задач с комментами у меня определена так:

```
$this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\TaskComments', 'task_id', array(
    'alias' => 'comments'
));
```

В итоге там же в модели задач определяю новую функцию

```
public function getSortedComments()
{
    return $this->getComments(array(
        'order' => 'date DESC'
    ));
}
```

А потом обращаюсь к отсортированным комментариям как

```
task->sortedcomments
```

Кривой вариант?